# PHP array output to a javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to connect a database with php and display result dynamically using javascript.
Here's What i am trying to do -

```
<?php
function mainMenu($q){
$res=array();;
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);   
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    array_push($res, "
    <li>
       <a class='gn-icon ".mysql_real_escape_string($r[0])."'>".mysql_real_escape_string($r[1])."
       </a>
    </li>");
}
return $res;
} ?>
```

Now here is the html , which definitely works

```
<ul id="sidemenu" class="gn-menu">
    <?php 
        $a=mainMenu($q);
        foreach ($a as $value) {
            echo $value;
        }
    ?>                       
</ul>
```

but when i try this -

```
<script> 
$('#sidemenu').html(<?php 
    $b=mainMenu($q);
            foreach ($b as $value) {
           echo "$value";
}
 ?>);
</script>
```

It doesnt work the, i just see blank space in my source and nothing is printed in the list, can anyone tell me where i am going wrong...

Comment: Try with `json_encode`.

Comment: `<a class='gn-icon ".mysql_real_escape_string($r[0])."'>` should be `urlencode`

Comment: `.html('<? your_code?>')`. QUOTES

Comment: And use `implode` instead of `foreach` while printing.

Comment: I got an error Unexpected token ILLEGAL while using .html('<?php 
    $b=mainMenu($q);
            foreach ($b as $value) {
           echo "$value";
 ?>') and .html('<?php 
    $b=mainMenu($q);
            foreach ($b as $value) {
           echo $value;
 ?>')

Comment: @u_mulder `""` quotes, becase he uses `''` quotes in output )

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function mainMenu($q) {
  $res=array();
  $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);   
  while( $r = $q->fetch() ) {
    array_push($res, "<li><a class='gn-icon ".mysql_real_escape_string($r[0])."'>".mysql_real_escape_string($r[1])."</a></li>");
  }
  return $res;
} 
?>

<script> 
$('#sidemenu').html("<?=implode('',mainMenu($q))?>");
</script>
```

Comment: $("#sidemenu").html("<?php 
$b=mainMenu($q);
$c=implode('',$b);
echo $c; 
?>"); 
It doesnt Work

Comment: Oh, Javascript does not allow newlines in string literals, so you must clean them or generate one-line HTML

Comment: Okay yeah got it this way 
$('#sidemenu').html(<?php    $b=mainMenu($q);
        $c = implode('',$b);
        echo mysql_real_escape_string("$c");
      ?>);

Comment: Yeah, urlencode, doesnt work here i tried and it gave me some weird encoded codes in my script tag when i viewed it in firebug

Comment: `urlencode` is completely wrong here, it will be good for `<a href="<?...?>">`

Comment: No actually someone suggested to use urlencode thats why i gave it a shot

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the single quote in your output using "Backslash",

```
<a class=\'gn-icon ".mysql_real_escape_string($r[0])."\'>".mysql_real_escape_string($r[1])."   </a>
```

and you need use the .html like this,

```
.html('<?php $b=mainMenu($q); foreach ($b as $value) { echo $value;} ?>')
```

Comment: I think i did the same think but it wont work, since the output is html with new line characters and quotes so i had to use mysql_real_escape_string() function to make it work

Comment: Oh right..So you have tried adding the "Blackslash" like this <a class=\'gn-icon ? Because I just ran your code with this change in my server and it worked!!

Comment: It might because from your sql end nothing will be returned , but for me the problem is with the sql result , which has the tags so had to use the function to escape the output from the sql